# Trying to prove the complexity of binary search is O(log(n))

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, binary-search

I'm trying to proof Complexity for Binary search. In Wikipedia says, that worst case scenario is log(n). This means:

If I have array with 16 elements, log(16) is 4. I should have max 4 calls to find element in array.

My java code:

```
class Main{
      int search(int[] array, int number, int start, int end) {
            System.out.println("Method call");
            int half = (end - start) / 2;

            if (array[start + half] == number) {
                return array[start + half];
            }
            if (array[start + half] < number) {
                return search(array, number, start + half, end);
            } else {
                return search(array, number, start, end - half);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
            for (int i : array) {
                System.out.println(i);
                new Main().search(array, i, 0, array.length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ideaone code: http://ideone.com/8Sll9n

and output is:

```
1
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
2
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
3
Method call
Method call
Method call
4
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
5
Method call
Method call
6
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
7
Method call
Method call
Method call
8
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
9
Method call
10
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
11
Method call
Method call
Method call
12
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
13
Method call
Method call
14
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
15
Method call
Method call
Method call
16
Method call
Method call
Method call
Method call
```

Everything is fine except searching for 1. There i have 5 "Method call"  which means 5  is greater than log(16).

My assumption is that maybe I'm wrong counting calls. Could someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: BTW log(16) == 1.2 https://www.google.com/search?q=log+16&oq=log+16

Comment: @sanbhat: Log(16) is 4, when calculated using base 2. To convert to base 2 when using a standard calculator or google, do the sum then divide by the required log, i.e. do log(16) / log(2) = 4

Comment: For complexity purposes, the base of the logarithm is irrelevant. With regard to binary search, base 2 is intuitive because we half the interval at every step. On another note, you don't prove the complexity of algorithms by checking the way your implementation of it works; proofs have to be done formally.

Comment: Big-O notation (basically) ignores constant factors. So, for example, O(g(n)) = O(2.g(n)), or equivalently for any constant. You may want to give [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) a read through.

Comment: and similarly O(log(n)) = O(log(n)+1)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191666/how-to-prove-o-log-n-is-true-for-a-binary-search-algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complexity of Binary search for an input of size of `n` is **O(log<sub>a</sub> n)** for `a > 1`. The very nature of the algorithm suggests that `a=2`, because at every iteration the search space is getting halved.

The code provided by you is also working fine. The confusion regarding the complexity of the algorithm has occurred because you ignored the hidden constant involved in the Big-Oh notation for complexity.

The statement `f(n)= O(g(n))` means that `f(n) ≤ cg(n)`. In your case, you forgot to acknowledge this constant `c`. `c` could veryl well be as large as **100000000000** or as small as **0.000000001**. This is one problem associated with Big-Oh notation. For many practical purposes an asymptotically more complex algorithm might out perform an asymptotically simpler algorithm due to the involvement of a very large or small constant.

For example the algorithm **g = O(1000000000 n)** will give poor performance when compared with algorithm **h = O(n<sup>2</sup>)**, for `n < 1000000000`.

So the conclusion is that you can not prove the complexity of an algorithm simply by counting the number of instructions executed because of the involvement of the hidden constant. You need to have rigorous mathematical methods to get a proof.

For example an algorithm `f` executing **100** instructions for an input size `n=10` could be,

**O(n)** if c is **10** such that **f(n) = O(10 n)**.

**O(n<sup>2</sup>)** if c is **1** such that **f(n) = O(1 n<sup>2</sup>)**.

**O(n<sup>3</sup>)** if c is **0.1** such that **f(n) = O(0.1 n<sup>3</sup>)**.

Answer (score 2):

In Big O notation, constants can be ignored because as the value of input N increases, there will not be any change in complexity due to constant factor and it becomes negligible.

Here, In binary search 1 extra call is happening. Even if you take billion numbers, it will still be at the most 1 extra call. Hence it becomes negligible and you need not count.